# define a `extern` var in C language, xcode send a `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`

Tags: xcode, extern

This question is hard to describe, I'll try my best.
Ok, here is the detail:

1. I have a public head file, named `header.h`;
2. define a `extern int a;` in header.h;
3. create `test1.c` and include `header.h`;
4. use var `a` in `test1.c`, but xcode give an error:`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`;

I tried to delete `extern`, and this question is gone. I searched `extern` in google, they said that if you don't add `extern`, xcode will auto add `extern`.Actually, there is difference between add `extern` by yourself and add `extern` by xcode. 
What's difference between then?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you declare a variable `extern`, that's a promise to the compiler, "Trust me, this will be there when you need it."  It doesn't make the variable, it just tells the compiler that it's declared for real somewhere, and the compiler doesn't need to know where.

You lied to the compiler. You didn't actually declare the variable anywhere, you just said you would. Then when the linker looked for it, it couldn't find it.

When you took away the `extern`, that turned the promise of a variable into an actual declaration. The compiler didn't have to believe you, it just made the variable like you told it to. But because it was in a header, if you included that variable in two different code files and compiled them into separate object files, when you tried to link them you would get an error about duplicate symbols. The proper way to use `extern` is to declare the variable `extern` in the header file and then declare it for real in the implementation (`.c`) file.

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

extern int a;

#endif
```

test1.c

```
#include "header.h"

int a = 5;

...
```

Then you can access the same variable `a` from a different c file.

test2.c

```
#include "header.h"

int foo() {
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer is quite clear. I just hear about `extern`, but I didn't know. This will be helpful. Thank you very much.